# C# JSON DeserializeObject, keep getting nullreference

Tags: c#, json

I know there are a lot of questions regarding JSON spread all over the internet and here on StackOverflow. But I can't get my JSON to work as it should, so I hope I can get some help around here.
[Working in C#, Visual Studio]

I've got the following code:

```
public void CheckRFID(string RFIDtag) {
    [...SOME WORKING CODE]
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();            
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());  

    currentuser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentuser[0].UserID);
}
```

This code keeps giving me "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Database.dll. Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

As you can see I'm writing the response to debug log to see if I get a JSON, the result of this debug is `[{"ID":"2","username":"IJK","gender":"F","color":"yellow"}]`. Looks like a proper JSON line to me.

So, I'm stuck. I have no idea where to look, what I've done wrong...

And just for more info, this is the User.cs class:

```
public class User {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you tell your platform you're working on? Winforms? ASP.NET Webforms? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Yeah Sorry, will edit the post.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentuser[0].UserID); is throwing exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StreamReader().ReadToEnd()` call will advance the source stream (`response.GetResponseStream()`) to the end. Because of that the second time you are creating it you will get an empty string back. This will result in `currentuser` being `null`.

Change your code like this:

```
public void CheckRFID(string RFIDtag)
{
    [...SOME WORKING CODE]
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string responseString = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseString);  

    currentuser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(responseString);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentuser[0].UserID);
}
```

You should also expect to have default value in your `UserID` property as it correct name should be `ID' (so it will not be bound properly) - I advice you change the name.

Comment: Besides that string response should have different name it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Serellyn Sorry I have used the same name for variable twice, edited, should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The first field on the JSON response is ID, not UserID, the name should not be the same?

Comment: Why would that cause a null reference exception?

Comment: If the json string and the class's property don't match, then UserID will be null. So, `currentUser[0].UserID` will evaluate to `null`. And his debug statement will evaluate to `WriteLine(null);`. None of these would throw a null ref exception.

Comment: It just skip field, if you have different name

Comment: Not the answer but a good thing to take a look at, I indeed need to change it to ID instead of UserID. Thanks for noticing Salvatore :)